# Exclude all rows if same value in column a is found multiple times in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to check if lead_id is multiple times in the table, and if yes, exclude from query? The reason is that I only want to add new rows if the status_id = 1 AND if there are no other status_id/rows found for that lead_id.

The database is designed in a way that for each status update it creates a new row. So the old row has an older timestamp and remains in the DB table, and these will be shown on the front-end in a status history component. But since it is designed this way, I can't simply say: give every user with status 1, a new status update. Because then it will add a row for every lead_id, since all leads will enter the DB with status_id 1.

Query I was using so far:

```sql
INSERT INTO `lead_has_status` (`lead_id`, `lead__status_id`, `comment`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
SELECT (`lead_id`, 13, "", `created_at`, `updated_at`)
WHERE `lead__status_id` = 1 AND
```

What the data looks like:

| lead_id | status_id | moredata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | data |
| 1 | 12 | data |
| 2 | 1 | data |
| 2 | 14 | data |
| 3 | 1 | data |
| 4 | 1 | data |
| 5 | 1 | data |
| 6 | 1 | data |

For every new lead (form submission) it will create a row and gives the lead a status_id of 1 (status: new). I do need to bulk update 200+ leads from 1 to another status_id, but with the query I have right now it will update every single row containing the status_id of 1. What I want is that it will first check if the lead_id is only there in the table once, and if true, add a new row with the updated status_id.

So after the sql query it will need to look like this:

| lead_id | status_id | moredata |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | data |
| 1 | 12 | data |
| 2 | 1 | data |
| 2 | 14 | data |
| 3 | 1 | data |
| 3 | 12 | data |
| 4 | 1 | data |
| 4 | 12 | data |
| 5 | 1 | data |
| 5 | 12 | data |
| 6 | 1 | data |
| 6 | 12 | data |

TLDR: If lead_id is only found once in the table, add new row with status_id.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Please edit your question to show sample data before the query and expected data after the query. Post the data as plain text, **not** images, formatted as "code".

Comment: Which MySQL Version you are using and have the table an unique id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your table has a an unique id per row then you can use a query like this

```
INSERT INTO `lead_has_status` (`lead_id`, `lead__status_id`, `comment`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
SELECT (`lead_id`, 13, "", `created_at`, `updated_at`)
FROM `lead_has_status` l
WHERE `lead__status_id` = 1 AND NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT 1 FROM lead_has_status 
  WHERE `lead_id` = l.`lead_id` AND id <> l.id );
```

and without id

```
INSERT INTO `lead_has_status` (`lead_id`, `lead__status_id`, `comment`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
SELECT (`lead_id`, 13, "", `created_at`, `updated_at`)
FROM `lead_has_status` l
WHERE `lead__status_id` = 1 AND  () 
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lead_has_status 
  WHERE `lead_id` = l.`lead_id`) = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just started working here so the whole project/codebase is new for me.  There is no unique id. The only columns available per row are: lead_id(which can be duplicated), status_id, comments, timestamps. So the only thing I need and want to check is whether lead_id is there for one time or multiple times in the table. I did edit my posts with the tables.

Comment: @DennisKr - so you can test my answer

Comment: I did but I get an error: #1054 - Onbekende kolom 'id' in where clause

I did change the query a bit since there was an syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO `lead_has_status`(
    `lead_id`,
    `lead__status_id`,
    `comment`,
    `created_at`,
    `updated_at`
)
SELECT
    `lead_id`,
    13,
    "",
    `created_at`,
    `updated_at`
FROM
    `lead_has_status` l
WHERE
    `lead__status_id` = 1 AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        lead_has_status
    WHERE
        `lead_id` = l.`lead_id` AND id <> l.id
);
```

Comment: @DennisKr - i have add a answer without id field